# CloudOnce breaks in Unity 5.6

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.1

I got CloudOnce working on every Unity version, but in latest 5.6 i get this error:

```
Assets/Extensions/CloudOnce/Internal/Editor/Utils/AndroidManifestModifier.cs(191,83):
error CS0117: UnityEditor.AndroidSdkVersions' does not contain a definition for AndroidApiLevel10'
```

And this is inside the code.

```
if (PlayerSettings.Android.minSdkVersion > AndroidSdkVersions.AndroidApiLevel10)
{
    gameCircleUserInterface.Add(new XAttribute(xmlns + "hardwareAccelerated", "false"));
}
```

Using CloudOnce for Unity in Android:
https://github.com/jizc/CloudOnce

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in v2.3.4. Current version is v2.5.0: https://github.com/jizc/CloudOnce/releases